# Replace values in a list based on conditions

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list with negative and positive numbers

```
list = {-1, -2, 1, 2}
```

and I want to replace all negative values with 0 and all positive values with 1 simultaneously. I only managed to replace one value at a time and don't know how to add a second condition. I did the following

```
list /. x_ /; x<0->1
```

I want something like:

```
 list /. x_ /; {x<0->0 && x>0->1}
```

but this does not work. So how to add a second condition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There a number of approaches. The desired behaviour of zero has not been specified.

Examples:

```
UnitStep[list]
Boole[# > 0] & /@ list
list /. {x_?Negative -> 0, x_?Positive -> 1}
HeavisideTheta[list]
(Unitize@# + Sign@#)/2 &@list
```

`UnitStep[0]` yields 1

The `Boole` approach will also yield zero but could be modified as desired.

The replacement rules has not specified zero so will leave it unchanged.

`HeavisideTheta[0]` yields `HeavisideTheta[0]`

The `Unitize`,`Sign` will yield 0.

There are other approaches.

Comment: list/. {x_?Negative -> 0, x_?Positive -> 1} worked for me. I don't understand why list /. {x_<0 -> 0, x_>0 -> 1}, does not work, I did not know ?Negatvie and ?Positive before.

Comment: You  can use list /. {x_ /; x < 0 -> 0, x_ /; x > 0 -> 1}, see the documentation on Condition.

Comment: I believe UnitStep[0] results in 1. I like the solution Sign[list] rather than Boole[#.0] & /@ list. I prefer using built-in functions whenever they work. From a learning perspective the functional approaches are good.

Comment: @JackLaVigne yes you are correct...apologies I will correct;)

Comment: …`Boole[Thread[list > 0]]` will work nicely.

Comment: @J. M. very nice...always learn something...:) will leave as comment unless you think I should append with attribution of course :)

Comment: It's entirely your call. I just shared what I do in these situations. :)

Answer (score 5):

These s/b considerably faster on large lists than solutions posted so far:

For integer lists:

```
UnitStep[Subtract[list, 1]]
```

For real lists:

```
 UnitStep[Subtract[Sign@list, 1]]
```

And I'd venture this will be quickest:

```
Clip[list, {0, 0}, {0, 1}]
```

Comment: (rasher) the first two are essentially correction to map 0 to 0 (noting the dealing with zero was not specified in OP)...`Clip` very nice :)

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {-1, -2, 1, 2, 0} 
Floor[(1 + Sign[#])/2]&/@list
```

Note that 0 is replaced by 0.

If you prefer to replace 0 by 1, you must use:

```
Ceiling[(1 + Sign[#])/2]&/@list
```