# Add a number to each negative element of a matrix

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I have the next matrix (`Dimensions: {178, 178, 3}`):

```
{{-1.22,2.44,3.14},{1.22,0.54,0.01},{1.21,-0.14,-2.31},{0.21,1.24,-0.42},...,{1.24,-0.25,1.34},{3.14,-3.14,-2.89}}
```

I want to add some quantity to each negative number of the matrix. Is it possible do that with control strucuture in Mathematica? How can I do it? thnk!

Comment: `mat /. x_?Negative :> x + 5`?

Comment: related: [Replace values in a list based on conditions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87519/142)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This operation is pretty easy to do in Matheamtica. Let `mat` be your matrix and `val` your value. The you simply do

```
mat/. {x_ /; Negative[x] :> x + val}
```

If you want me to explain it just ask.

Comment: The problem with this is that it won't work if the elements are symbolic expressions rather than numbers. How could that be modified to make it work in that case as well?

Answer (score 4):

Say `mat` is your matrix and `val` is the number you wish to add to all the negative values:

```
mat - val Clip[Sign[mat], {-1, 0}]
```

Another similar method:

```
mat + val (1 - UnitStep[mat])
```

Comment: Furthermore, if `mat` is a packed array, it will stay packed with this method.

Comment: You might give `mat + Clip[mat, {0, 0}, {val, 0}]` consideration, I'd imagine faster (at least on packed arrays)...

Comment: Now I am curious. Has this solution any advatanges to a simple replace? E.g. far higher perfomance?