# How do I replace elements in a list matching a pattern?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list: {0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6}.
I want to replace all the elements that are greater than 1 with the integer 1.  In other words, I want Mma to return the list {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}.

Comment: `Unitize[data]` or `Clip[data]`, maybe?

Comment: lst = Table[RandomInteger[10], 10]
Map[Min[#, 5] &, lst]
5 as an example. You should use 1.

Comment: `lst /. x_ /; x > 1 -> 1 `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just googled "wolfram mathematica replace if". Based on the [first link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87519/replace-values-in-a-list-based-on-conditions) I was able to figure it out in a minute!

```
lst = {0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6};
lst /. {x_?(# > 1 &) -> 1}
{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

Answer (score 7):

Usual approach would be to use `ReplaceAll`:

```
list = {0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6};
list/.{x_?(# > 1 &) -> 1}
```

A slick approach would be

```
Boole /@ GreaterEqualThan[1] /@ list
```

Or even

```
Map[Min[#, 1] &, list]
```

Faster approach would be to use:

```
Unitize[list]
Clip[list]
```

All of them would give you:

```
{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

I just ran `list = Table[RandomInteger[10], 100000]` and used Mr.Wizard's [timeAvg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8652/61441) function:

```
list /. {x_?(# > 1 &) -> 1} // timeAvg
Boole /@ GreaterEqualThan[1] /@ list // timeAvg
Map[Min[#, 1] &, l] // timeAvg
Unitize[l] // timeAvg
Clip[l] // timeAvg
```

> 0.0690836
>
> 0.0559747
>
> 0.00204779
>
> 0.000139352
>
> 0.00022492

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Comment: @geoffrey, glad that was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6};
```

**1.**

Using `SequenceReplace` (new in 11.3)

```
SequenceReplace[list, {Except @ 0} -> 1]
```

{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

**2.**

Some position-based solutions

```
p = Position[list, x_ /; x > 1]
```

{{5}, {6}, {7}, {8}}

```
MapAt[1 &, p] @ list;

ReplaceAt[_ :> 1, p] @ list;

ReplacePart[p -> 1] @ list;
```

All return

{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = {0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6};
```

---

Using `SubsetMap`:

```
p = Position[lst, n_ /; n > 1];

SubsetMap[Subtract @@ {#, #} + 1 &, #, p] &@lst
```

*Result*:

> {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

Or using `Cases`:

```
Cases[lst, n_ :> If[n > 1, 1, n]]
```

*Result*:

> {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

Answer (score 1):

This is a long comment which wouldn't fit in the provided space, so here it goes. The conclusion is that good test data results in more general and compliant solutions.

-- **TLDR**

OP requires: `to replace all the elements that are greater than 1 with the integer 1`.

It is almost implied that list members are natural numbers and the answers conform to the provided data.

---

The documentation states that `Unitize`:

`gives 0 when x is zero, and 1 when x has any other numerical value.`

Hence in this context, negative numbers are also converted to `1` which is not desired. Also, a non-numerical value would remain unevaluated.

---

For a list that has elements with other `Head`s and `Sign`s, a possible solution could be:

```
lst = {0, 1, 1.1, -2, 2, 2, 0.9, 6, a, 3 + 4 I, 1/2, 17/3};

Clear[g]
g[n_Real | n_Rational | n_Integer] := 
 Clip[n, {-∞, 1}, {n, 1}]
g[n_] := n

{lst, Cases[lst, n_ :> g[n]]} // Grid
```

---

[image]

Comment: (+1) An interesting observation, since the case you address is more general.